# ElasticSearch on Alias not working after 5 days

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating an alias with 14 indices. It's working for on an average of 5 days. Later alias is not picking the data from all indices later after.

I need to delete and create alias again in order to fetch the data from all indices.

Any problem? All responses appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a little more info? Like what platform your ElasticSearch is running on, ElasticSearch version, etc.

Comment: Thanks Dan for the response. We were working on the analytics on the network switches performance. We were using the 14 indices under one alias. Same alias is been used in Kibana for dashboards. while using alias as I said above, after 5 days its not working for most of the indices. I need to delete and create the alias once again to fetch the data from all the indices.

Comment: Where I work we have ElasticSearch reindex itself every night during off-hours using a Cron job. Not sure if this is an option for you or if it would help your problem.

Comment: Thanks Dan.. I will try this option.

Comment: Hi dan,
Can you please provide best reference to create Cron job for the "curl -X POST"